# Redirect www to no-www

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following to redirect a without-www address to a with-www address:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Hostname">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mydomain\.com$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But know I would like to redirect a sub domain in the inverse way so:

```
www.blog.mydomain.com would become blog.mydomain.com
```

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: IF you can change your match URL to a regular expression that looks sort of like "([a-zA-Z0-9]*.blog.mydomain.com)", you should be able to change the redirect action to http://blog.mydomain.com

Comment: You may want to eliminate the conditions though, if you do. Or make them more relevant to your site.

Comment: Could you, please, give an example? I am not sure I understand what you are saying? Eliminate the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this should work:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Hostname">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog\.mydomain\.com$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="//blog.mydomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This checks if `HTTP_HOST` part is not `blog.mydomain.com` or `localhost` and if it is not, it redirects to `blog.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Example based on my comments above.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Hostname">
      <match url="([a-zA-Z0-9]*.blog.mydomain.com)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mydomain\.com$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="blog.mydomain.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**IMPORTANT:** The key thing to note, is that this will only work if your server still accepts www.blog.mydomain.com. Since this is a redirect, that means that the server hit, which hosts this redirect, is actually hosting either www.blog.mydomain.com or *.blog.mydomain.com. If it isn't, then the DNS records will never route the browser to the site in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you asked for is, if any domain comes through that has a `www.` in the front, strip it off. That's easy:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Hostname">
      <match url="^www\.(.+)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```